# How to display data from html form to table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have html form which accepts user details.And I want to display html form data into table. So how to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: what did you try please?

Comment: As mentioned in question, i just want to display html form details in tabular format.

Comment: You should provide atleast one own attempt to solve your problem. Also example of your source would be helpful.

Comment: I got the answer,how to do this. Thanx for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like you are not using server-side posting, but you are just trying to put information on a form and show it in the table on the same page. Am I right?

If so then, this is an example of the function you can use:

JavaScript:

```
function addRowToTable() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.size = 40;
  cellRight.appendChild(el);  
 }

function removeRowFromTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
```

For the full implementation, Please follow the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19532/Dynamic-Table-using-html-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to take a HTTP GET parameter and post the form using HTTP GET with HTML and receive the form parameters with jQuery over HTTP GET. JQuery or some JavaScript framework could also do HTTP POST, but you would want to keep this usecase simple if you don't have too many requirements.

If you need help writing the code you can do it in www.jsfiddle.net and we will help there or we can post code here if the task is over your capabilities.